# PostgreSQL: Set a number from a narrow range within a specific group - a very specific and unusual aviation related task

Tags: postgresql

I am working with table that contain aircraft information used in an external program. The aircraft in the table are be grouped numerically, groups 1,2,3... etc.

One of the fields of info is a transponder code. These codes are 4 place integers with digits restricted to 0-7. The smallest allowable code is 0000 and the largest 7777. These codes are further restricted by range. So a specific set may be within a range like 0400-0477 or 5100-7277. Additionally, there are 5 "special use" codes like 1200 that cannot be assigned. Finally, aircraft within a group must have a unique code but may match other groups. The codes need not be random, just within the range and not repeated within a group.

So the table with a range of 0400-0477 may look like:

```
ID  |CALLSIGN  |GROUP |CODE
1   |N1234     |1     |0402
2   |N345      |1     |0403
3   |N4567     |2     |0403
4   |N789      |2     |0404
5   |N2456     |3     |0401
6   |N1357     |3     |0402
```

The goal would be to set a range, run a script and create the codes for several thousand aircraft while following the above stated rules. I can create numbers starting at a range beginning but how do I avoid the 8-9s in all the digits? I'm assuming I will end up with a function that loops through each digit one at a time but I wondered if there was a better idea.

I'm using PGAdmin III 1.22.2 and postgres 9.4.6

Comment: Please try this:  `select to_char(n, '0000') from generate_series(400,477) as gs(n) where n::text !~ '[89]';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete example from my comment assumes you have this table:

```
select * from callsigns;
┌────┬──────────┬───────────┬──────┐
│ id │ callsign │ group_num │ code │
├────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────┤
│  1 │ N1234    │         1 │      │
│  2 │ N345     │         1 │      │
│  3 │ N4567    │         2 │      │
│  4 │ N789     │         2 │      │
│  5 │ N2456    │         3 │      │
│  6 │ N1357    │         3 │      │
└────┴──────────┴───────────┴──────┘
(6 rows)
```

To update it according to your specification:

```
with tcodes as (
  select row_number() over (order by n) as rn, 
         to_char(n, '0000') as tcode
    from generate_series(400, 477) as gs(n)
   where n::text !~ '[89]'
), assign as (
  select id, 
         row_number() over (partition by group_num
                                order by id) as rn
    from callsigns
)
update callsigns
   set code = t.tcode
  from assign a
       join tcodes t
         on t.rn = a.rn
 where a.id = callsigns.id;

UPDATE 6

select * from callsigns;
┌────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│ id │ callsign │ group_num │ code  │
├────┼──────────┼───────────┼───────┤
│  1 │ N1234    │         1 │  0400 │
│  2 │ N345     │         1 │  0401 │
│  3 │ N4567    │         2 │  0400 │
│  4 │ N789     │         2 │  0401 │
│  5 │ N2456    │         3 │  0400 │
│  6 │ N1357    │         3 │  0401 │
└────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────┘
(6 rows)
```

You can verify that the digits `8` and `9` do not appear in the possibles by running this:

```
select to_char(n, '0000') from generate_series(400,477) as gs(n) where n::text !~ '[89]';
```

Comment: Wow, easier than I thought! I'll play with that. Thanks a lot. I left out a length constraint of 4 characters it seems as I'm getting a "value too long for type character(4)" error.

Comment: Turned out to be an extra leading space in the code output. All fixed! Thanks again!

Comment: I also added a "NOT IN" to the where statement to skip the special use codes. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least make things simpler by treating the numbers as octal, since then everything is 0-7 anyway. Convert the ranges from octal to decimal, for example, 0400->256, 0477->319, then loop between them and convert back. You probably need them as strings anyway to keep the preceding zeroes, so it's pretty simple with division and modulo, then convert to character types.

Second option would be to have four variables, each for one digit, and loop manually 0-7 carrying to next one when done. Not sure which one would be prettier or more performant.

Skipping specific codes could be handled with a few `if`s handling several loops, like "if start < first then loop between start and first special" and then the next range and the next. Don't need to check for five special values in a sea of thousands of valid ones for each number that way at least.

Comment: Thanks, great idea. I appreciate your suggestion.